# Using in inside linq where condition

Tags: c#, linq

```
select * 
  from laqTasks t 
 where t.Duty in (1, 2, 3)
```

How to use in inside the Linq, should I use contains.

```
var UpdateLaqTasks = dbContext.Tasks.SingleOrDefault
(p => p.Room == roomId
      && p.Duty IN(1, 3, 29, 206))
```

Thanks,
N.ShanthaKumar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in Linq you can use `Contains`, here is the code that should work.

```
var dutyList = new List<int> { 1, 3, 29, 206 };

var UpdateLaqTasks = dbContext.Tasks.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Room == roomId && dutyList.Contains(p.Duty));
```